# Python regular expression search

Tags: python, regex, search, findall

I was trying to search for all those phrases with the key word 'car':

e.g. text = 'alice: speed car, my red car, new car', I would like to find 'speed car', 'my red car', 'new car'.

```
import re
text = 'alice: speed car, my red car, new car'
regex = r'([a-zA-Z]+\s)+car'
match = re.findall(regex, text)
if match:
    print(match)
```

but the above code yields:

```
["speed ", "red ", "new "]
```

instead of

```
["speed car", "my red car", "new car"]
```

which is expected?

Answer (score 4):

Problem is you're not capturing `'car'` in your regex, put the whole regex inside a `()` and and use `?:` for the inner regex to make it a non-capturing group.

```
>>> regex = r'((?:[a-zA-Z]+\s)+car)'
>>> text = 'alice: speed car, my red car, new car'
>>> re.findall(regex, text)
['speed car', 'my red car', 'new car']
```